# Hadoop - Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to hadoop and was trying to run the WordCount tutorial. I am getting the following error: **Unsupported major.minor version 51.0**. I have seen some posts with the same error and I understand that the reason is that I am compiling my java with one JDK and running it with another. **I already know I compile it with jdk 1.7 but how can I tell which version used to run it?**

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

It must be some incompatibility with your jre version. Are you using jre 7 to run it?

On the other hand, you it's easier to compile a lower version from the source. Try this (for e.g. jdk 1.6):

```
javac -target 1.6 wordcount.java
```

Comment: How can I check which version of the jre I use to run it?

Comment: Just call `java -version`. Or if you use an IDE, search on it's site.